# Running python in yarn/spark cluster mode using virtualenv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv, hadoop-yarn

My python app on yarn/spark does not recognize the requirements.txt file to create a virtualenv on the worker nodes, and continues to use the global environment. Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Spark version: 2.0.1

submit script after running `pip freeze > requirements-test.txt` from within the virtual environment that I want to recreate at the nodes:

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true  --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.requirements=/mnt/py_env/requirements-test.txt --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/mnt/anaconda2/bin/virtualenv --conf spark.pyspark.python=/mnt/py_env/test/bin/python /home/hadoop/python/spark_virtualenv.py
```

My requirements-test.txt file:

```
dill==0.2.7.1
Lifetimes==0.8.0.0
numpy==1.13.1
pandas==0.20.3
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.10.0
```

My `/home/hadoop/python/spark_virtualenv.py`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
#import lifetimes
if __name__ == "__main__":
  sc = SparkContext(appName="Simple App")
  import numpy as np
  sc.parallelize(range(1,10)).map(lambda x : np.__version__).collect()
  print "//////////// works! //////////"
  #print lifetimes.__version__
  print  np.__file__
```

From the output, I see that it is still importing only my global numpy package and not the one in the virtual environment:

```
//////////// works! //////////
/mnt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc
```

PS: I have anaconda2 installed on all nodes of my cluster

One other point: If my spark-submit option is changed to `--deploy-mode cluster` then the output is different:

```
//////////// works! //////////
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda might have a preferred way of doing it through Conda, but one thought is to add the lifetimes utils.py, estimation.py, etc all the files from the package with the lines:

SparkContext.addPyFile("/fully/articulated/path/file.py")